# The dialog to change your job search status leads to a raw JSON response

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Here's the dialog that got me there:
[image: teh dialog]

I got that from a psuedobeginner introduction on the sidebar.

The output, for example, is: `{"success":true,"newState":"NotLooking","message":"done"}`